# post filter in Spring Cloud Gateway is not responding if downstream service is down

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-gateway

I am implementing a post filter in Spring Cloud Gateway. This is working fine if my downstream service is running. But, if my downstream service is NOT running, I am getting 500 Internal Server Error and my post filter is not executing.

What I need: I want to check what status code is comming from downstream. In this case I should receive status code 500, then I want to send back a Custom Response Header with some message.

```
public GlobalFilter customGlobalPostFilter() {
    return (exchange, chain) -> chain.filter(exchange)
        .then(Mono.just(exchange))
        .map(serverWebExchange -> {
          //adds header to response
          serverWebExchange.getResponse().getHeaders().set("CUSTOM-RESPONSE-HEADER",
              HttpStatus.OK.equals(serverWebExchange.getResponse().getStatusCode()) ? "It worked": "It did not work");
          return serverWebExchange;
        })
        .then();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try onErrorResume handler exception.